# What is the importance of Dhwajasthamba in any of the temples that we go?

Tags: krishna, temple, dharma

It is said to be the respect that the King Mayura Dhwaja has earned by donating his complete left half of his body to Lord Sri Krishna in one of his leelas?

Is that the reason why we need to pray to the Dhwajasthamba first even before we offer our prayers to the main diety in the temple?

Kindly provide if there are any citations of this in any of the Holy scriptures!